# preg_match error, currency converter, undefined offset: 1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am developing a currency converter using PHP and Google Finance as part of my system design class.

Can you help me fix the error:

"Notice: Undefined offset: 1"?

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<form action="" method="POST">
Amount:
<input type="text" name="amount" /><br/><br/>
From:
<input type="text" name="from" /><br/><br/>
To:
<input type="text" name="to" /><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" id="convert" name="convert"/>  
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

function currency_convert($amount, $from, $to){
    $url='https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a='.$amount.'&from='.$from.'&to='.$to;
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match("/<span class=bld>(.*)<\/span>/",$data,$converted);
    echo $converted[1]; 
}

if(isset($_POST['convert'])){
    $amount=$_POST['amount'];
    $from=$_POST['from'];
    $to=$_POST['to'];
    currency_convert($amount, '$from', '$to');
}

?>
```

Comment: doesn't need to be quoted `'$from', '$to'`

Comment: Hi @Ghost. That feeling when you f'ed up by single quotations.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Enjoy! )

```
<?php

function currency_convert($amount, $from, $to){
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=' . $amount . '&from=' . $from . '&to=' . $to;
    $data = @file_get_contents($url);
    if (!$data) {
        return null;
    }
    if (!preg_match("/<span class=bld>(.*)<\/span>/", $data, $converted)) {
        return null;
    }
    $converted = explode(' ', $converted[1], 2);
    return (float)$converted[0];
}

if(isset($_POST['convert'])){
    $convertedAmount = currency_convert($_POST['amount'], $_POST['from'], $_POST['to']);
    echo $_POST['amount'] . ' ' . $_POST['from'] . ' = ' . number_format($convertedAmount, 2, '.', ' ') . ' ' . $_POST['to'] . "\n";
}
```

**Explanation:**
`'$to'` is not equal `$to` because `'strings in quotes'` doesn't parsing by PHP engine, only in `"double quotes"`. That is why your request is wrong and `file_get_contents` received another document with error. So, `preg_match` returned false and `$converted` was an empty array. That is why trying to get `$converted[1]` called notice.

Good luck!